# jQuery animate height in percentage scrolls to the top

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jQuery's `animate()` to change the height of a div:

```
$(this).animate({
  height: '60%'
});
```

The problem is that it automatically scrolls to the top of the div, which I don't want to happen. I've also noticed that this does not happen when I specify a height in pixels `height: '400px'`, but I really need a percentage here.

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/vdcqgjyn/3/

How can I prevent my div from scrolling to the top automatically? 
Thanks

---

EDIT (05/16/19)

I haven't found a proper solution yet, but a simple trick instead, using the fact a value in pixels will work:

```
let h = Math.round( $(this).parent().innerHeight() * 60/100 );
$(this).animate({
  height: h+'px'
});
```

This trick won't work in the live example, cause you need to have a parent with a fixed height.

Still curious to know whether this can be solved a cleaner way!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because when jQuery runs `animate()` on a dimensional property it sets `overflow: hidden` on the affected element. When the animation ends it resets `overflow` back to the original setting. As such, when reducing the value, the scroll position is then reverted to the top.

To fix this you need to override `overflow` on the element so that jQuery does not change it:

```
.div-animate.percentage,
.div-animate.pixels {
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

```js
$(".percentage").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).animate({
    height: '60%'
  });
});

$(".pixels").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).animate({
    height: '400px'
  });
});
```

```css
.div-animate {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  outline: solid 1px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.percentage {
  left: 10px;
}

.div-animate.percentage,
.div-animate.pixels {
  overflow: auto !important;
}

.pixels {
  left: 320px;
}

ul li {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
SCROLL THE DIV THEN CLICK IT

<div class="div-animate percentage">
  PERCENTAGE
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="div-animate pixels">
  PIXELS
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I don't like the use of `!important` here, but unfortunately there's currently no alternative as jQuery adds the `overflow` styling to the element in an inline `style` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very clear! However I just tried it in the fiddle and it doesn't seem to work for me?